# CMFCVisualManager custom theme for MFC MDI tabbed app

Tags: mfc-feature-pack

Does anyone have or can create a sample for a MFC MDI tabbed App custom theme using CMFCVisualManager ?
I may even pay for it..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You already examples in the MFC source, e.g. CMFCVisualManagerVS2005, CMFCVisualManagerOfficeXP. Just inherit from one of those and change the bits you want.